# How to load vba macros to the excel file from a text file by a C# code?

Tags: c#, excel, vba

My C# code has to create an Excel file with two Worksheets and output some data over there. Besides data columns, the Sheet 1 has to be enabled with a VBA macros which would allow a user to perform some mathematical calculations with provided data upon clicking on a particular cell. This VBA macros are stored in a text file, like `C:\VBA_MACROS\VBA1.txt.`

Right now I can do it manually, i.e.

1. C# code creates an Excel file and populates it with data.
2. I do a right click on Sheet1 and select an option "View Code".
3. I click on the button "Insert" from the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Menu and load the file `C:\VBA_MACROS\VBA1.txt`.
4. I close the VBA code window.

Question: can steps 2 - 4 be performed automatically by a C# code as well as the step 1? In this case a user would not have to perform them manually which would be a way more comfortable for her.

To be exact, this is how the application is created:

```
Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Worksheet worksheet2 = workbook.Sheets[2];

// output data to the worksheets
DataTable2Worksheet(tableMain, worksheet, verSize);
DataTable2Worksheet(tableExtra, worksheet2, 0);

// output workbook to the file
string fileDir = @"D:\MyTests\ExcelTests\";
Output2File(fileDir, workbook);
```

`DataTable2Worksheet` and `Output2File` functions are quite trivial, but how to attach the content of the text file to `worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1]` by using `AddFromFile` method?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need a reference to `Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;`.

Then you need to get a handle on the module you want to insert into. 
Then you can just use the [CodeModule.AddFromFile method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821352(v=office.15).aspx) to insert the code in your text file into the module.

```
VBE.VBProjects("NameOfProject").VBComponents.Item("NameOfWorksheet").CodeModule.AddFromFile("C:\Path\to\file.txt");
```

The default name for a newly created project is `"VBAProject"` and you the name of the component for a sheet is the name of the sheet.

So, for your particular case, you could add this line of code at the end of your snippet to insert the VBA into Sheet1.

```
application.VBE.VBProjects("VBAProject").VBComponents.Item("Sheet1").CodeModule.AddFromFile("C:\VBA_MACROS\VBA1.txt");
```

I just learned that another option is to use the [VBProject property of the Workbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.vbproject.aspx), which makes the call a little cleaner.

```
workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("Sheet1").CodeModule.AddFromFile("C:\VBA_MACROS\VBA1.txt");
```